# Org-ellipsis displayed inorrectly for some headlines only

Tags: org-mode, unicode, utf-8

So in order to customize my org mode files, I have

```
(setq org-ellipsis "⤵")
```

in my config, which seems to be a very popular customization (the arrow being U+2935). This works correctly **for the most part**. In some cases, the ellipsis character is displayed as a block as if I don't have the proper Unicode fonts set up; only I do because some headlines have the ellipsis displayed properly. Here's an example:

[image]

I tried to set up `utf-8` encoding for my files according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17537564/) but it didn't help. I'm new to emacs so I don't even know how to go about debugging this issue.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I noticed this behavior consistently on Debian Linux, Arch Linux and Mac OS X.

**EDIT 2 (another symptom)**

I have discovered the difference between the headlines that display properly and the ones that don't. It is so seemingly insignificant that I ignored it earlier. It seems any headlines that have a blank line before the start of the next headline cause the ellipsis to display improperly.
So for example in:

```
* Headline 1
  Contents

* Headline 2
  More contents
* Headline 3
  Last contents
```

The ellipsis for headlines 2 and 3 (when folded) displays correctly but a block is shown for headline 1. If I remove the blank line between headlines 1 and 2, the ellipsis for headline 1 is displayed correctly as well. What is going on here?

**EDIT 3**

If I remove the customization, the default ellipsis is displayed correctly for all headlines.

Comment: This happens only sometimes, but you aren't yet able to tell when/why it happens, I guess. I wonder if this might be an issue to report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. But perhaps someone here can help.

Comment: @Drew Right, I can't see a difference between the content of the different headlines to point me to why they're behaving differently. I'm hoping this is not a bug and this is just a silly newbie mistake that someone here can point out.

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce it (bleeding-edge versions of both org-mode and emacs).

Comment: If you remove the org-ellipsis customization, do the normal ellipses work as you would expect?

Comment: @NickD They do. I will add that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. It is due to the fact that `org` considers blank lines to be part of the headline's content by default. Following [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332479/org-mode-folding-considers-whitespace-as-content), I added

```
(setq org-cycle-separator-lines -1)
```

to my `init.el` and everything is now working as expected.

Comment: While that fixes the behaviour, I kind of get the feeling that something is missing. I would like to keep the old behaviour (with the default separator-lines value) but make it display whatever is not displaying.

Comment: @edmz I agree that this doesn't solve the core issue, but I'm afraid that tackling that is beyond my current level of experience with emacs.